# I cannot import swift 4 module's with Xcode 9.2

Tags: swift, xcode9.2, swift4.1

I have Xcode 9.2 and I am thinking I automatically have Swift 4.1. So I tried to import some modules like:

```
import Hero
import EGFormValidator
```

but it gives me an error saying it does not recognize those modules.
How can I access Swift 4.1 on my Xcode?

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming those are CocoaPods. Have you tried rebuilding it?

Comment: Xcode 9.2 uses Swift 4.0. Xcode 9.3 uses Swift 4.1.

Comment: @Sweeper I don't have cocoa pods installed in my computer, you think that is the problem?

Comment: @maddy ama upgrade asap

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using CocoaPods. Try to clean and then rebuild your project.

However make sure that you use the `.xcworkspace` and **not** the `.xcodeproj` file!